# Firebase Authenticate not working

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I'm intergrating firebase in my android application.
I execute step by step with document of firebase.
I complete step OAuth redirect URI to your Facebook app configuration.

[Link Ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login)

when I build the project. It crash in `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`with exception below:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null.

Build Gradle

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$playServicesVersion"

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServicesVersion"

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$playServicesVersion"

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$playServicesVersion"
     compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$playServicesVersion"


    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$androidSupportVersion"

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$androidSupportVersion"

    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$androidSupportVersion"

    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$androidSupportVersion"



    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Please help me.

Comment: def playServicesVersion = '9.6.1'

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem.